# How can I set a flag for a back button pressed on Dialog Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a fragment. On clicking one of the textview in the fragment a dialog fragment appears. The dialog fragment takes some input and when clicked on a button it passes the data to the parent fragment and dismisses.

I want to be able to know that if a user doesn't gives any input and presses back button, I want a flag to be initialized at my parent fragment. So that I can write my following code accordingly. The dialog fragment input is optional.

How can I implement this?

I tried using onKeyListener but I guess i didn't do it right.

Here is the code:

```
Flag = 0;

public void openDialog(View view){
    MyDialogFragment dialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(data);
    dialog.setTargetFragment(this,MY_REQUEST_CODE);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
    dialog.getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Flag = 1;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone point me in right direction? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is a DialogFragment necessary ? Can you use an AlertDialog instead ?

Comment: There is an overided method 'OnDismiss()' in 'DialogFragment', It get called when the dialog dismissed. Do your job over there.

Comment: @Wizard but the dismiss() method will be called even when I have taken input  and the button is pressed to return to parent fragment.